# probability density function 21

Tags: probability

If $$f(x)= \frac{2x+3}{24}:1\leq x \leq 4$$
$$f(x)= zero ,otherwise$$ 
Is a probability density function of a continuous random variable 
Find $$P(x> 3)$$
My solution is :
$$f(3) = \frac{9}{24}$$
$$f(4)=\frac{11}{24}$$
$$P(x>3)= \frac{1}{2} [\frac{9}{24}+\frac{11}{24}\times 1] =\frac{5}{12}$$
My question is : would not i subtract the value of $$f(3)$$ from the result above or not ? because the equality sign did not hold in the question ?

Comment: Why do you think that $P(x>3)=\frac12[f(3)+f(4)]$?

Comment: because it is of degree one ,i,e the area of the region bounded by this function and x-axis is the area of a trapizium whose parallel bases lengths are $$f(3) , f(4)$$ and its height is 1 @drhab

Comment: Then it is correct. There is no reason at all to subtract $f(3)$. The distribution is continuous (since it has a PDF) so that $P(X>3)=P(X\geq3)$.

Comment: Does this a special a property associated with the PDF ? @drhab

Comment: Every distribution that has a PDF will satisfy $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$. There also distributions that satisfy this and have no PDF. So having a PDF is sufficient for this but not necessary.

Comment: your method works because the density is a degree $1$ polynomial on $[1,4]$ but in many other cases the integral would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

If $f$ denotes a PDF of random variable $X$ then: $$P(X>x)=\int_x^{\infty}f(y)dy$$

---

edit:

Your solution is correct and gives you $P(X>3)=P(X\geq3)=\frac5{12}$.

Note that something like $f(3)$ - where $f$ is a PDF - cannot be recognized as a probability. In this a PDF is essentially different than a PMF (probability mass function).

Comment: may you give some illustration for $$f(3)$$ does not recognized as a probability ? and whats does it recognized as ? @drhab